# Enabling remote connection to SQL Server 2008 Express on Windows Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008-express, remote-connection

I am trying to connect to the SQL Server 2008 Express from my local machine but for some reasons I am not able to connect to the server.

- `sqlserver.exe` is allowed in the firewall
- TCP protocol is enabled
- `sqlexpress` is running
- allowing remote connections to the server

When I disabled the firewall for the public connections it is working fine

Any other suggestions please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from what I read I think the problem is the firewall
I came a cross an answer I didn't try it, it could be helpful 
the solution was found [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/37061/remote-connection-sql-server-not-working-but-if-firewall-disabled-it-does)

Comment: The above article was helped me out.

I just executed the command on the server and it works like charm

netsh firewall set portopening TCP 1433 "SQLServer"

Thanks